# Applying a SARIMA Equation, calculated in R, in SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, arima

I am creating a model to predict at least one quarter into the future. I used R to produce the results below and so far the model fits the data sufficiently well, in R that is. I was wondering how to put this equation/model into use via SQL. How do I apply these coefficients to an equation in SQL?

```
{

    >summary(f_aa)

     Forecast method: ARIMA(2,0,0)(1,1,0)[12]

     Model Information: Series: dots  ARIMA(2,0,0)(1,1,0)[12] 

     Coefficients:

            ar1     ar2     sar1
            0.3973  0.4954  -0.4858
      s.e.  0.1387  0.1396   0.1584

      sigma^2 estimated as 28493524:  log likelihood=-380.69 AIC=769.38  
      AICc=770.59   BIC=775.93
}
```

Comment: This is a *very* broad question. In SQL Server 2016 and above you can run deploy and run R packages on the server itself. Is that what you are asking? Check the [Use R in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-code-in-transact-sql-quickstart?view=sql-server-2017) walkthrough

Comment: I am using sql server 2012. I am trying to apply an equation for the sarima(2,0,0)(1,1,0)[12] model with the coefficients above.                        So, Yt = Yt-2 + 2Yt-1 ...

Comment: The [Create a predictive model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-create-a-predictive-model-r?view=sql-server-2017) shows how to create a predictive model using the packages already deployed with R. You may not *need* a custom function, or you may need one that's far simpler than what you have. Check the [R samples for Retail Forecasting on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/SQL-Server-R-Services-Samples/tree/master/RetailForecasting/SQLR) The Time series scripts use ARIMA

Comment: In this case, this is too broad. Essentially, you are asking how to execute a query to load data from SQL Server, apply a function to them and save the data back out. Why don't you upgrade to SQL Server 2017? The Express edition is free, and so it the *Developer* edition which has all the features of the Enterprise edition, without the production license.

Comment: There are many packages that can be used to *load*, eg RODBC. This [snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/new-components-in-sql-server-to-support-r?view=sql-server-2017#communication-channels-between-components) shows how to use it to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: I am fixed to 2012 as this is the only version of SQL that is available to me. I have already created the model in R. So much like a linear regression model I am trying to apply the arima equation, like the y=mx+c, to a report I am creating in SQL. I am never the less interested in the additional tips you gave me, but maybe not in this instance.

Comment: Then you'll have to load the data with rodbc, apply the function to them and write them out again with rodbc. Unless you mean, how to create a SQL function that performs the calculations?

Comment: Yes, how to create a SQL function that performs the calculation. How to apply the ARIMA equation, from the original query, to the raw data that is already in SQL Server.